# Chart.js drawing line between two points

Tags: javascript, chart.js

On my chart (just a horizontal line) I want to draw a second horizontal line. This second line is just a line between two arbitrary points. 
So far, I haven't manage to draw this second line. The second line is not rendered.

```
  // labels (dates)
  var startDate = new Date('2019-10-01'), endDate = new Date('2019-10-10');
  var dt = new Date(startDate);
  let labels = new Array();
  while (dt <= endDate) {
    labels.push(new Date(dt));
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
  }

  const numbers = new Array();
  const numbers1 = new Array();

  // data for first line (just a horizontal line)
  for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    numbers.push(5);
  }

  // data for the second line, also a horizontal line but smaller
  for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    if (a == 3 || a == 7) {
      numbers1.push(6);
    } else {
      numbers1.push(null);
    }
  }


  this.canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

  // display chart
  const myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Daily prices',
        data: numbers,
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'black'
      }, {
        label: 'Pattern',
        data: numbers1,
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'red'
      }]
    },
    options: {
      elements: {point: {radius: 0}},
      responsive: false,
      display: true
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chart.js does not draw a line between non-adjacent points, by default. This can be enabled, per dataset, with the [`spanGaps` property](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html?h=spangaps):

> If `true`, lines will be drawn between points with no or `null` data. If `false`, points with `NaN` data will create a break in the line.

```
...
{
    label: 'Pattern',
    data: numbers1,
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'red',
    spanGaps: true
}
...
```